# Override drupal's core include files

Tags: drupal, include

Specifically common.inc. I need to modify format_date, but I want to do it safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only override a few specific files (like session.inc or cache.inc), it is not possible to override common.inc.

However, you don't need to. See my answer to your other question: [Drupal not using custom time format type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670371/drupal-not-using-custom-time-format-type/5670759#5670759)